# NVIDIA driver installation issue on Ubuntu 22.04 real-time kernel 5.15.0-1044 for GT640 graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I am attempting to install an NVIDIA driver for my GT640 card on a system running the real-time kernel 5.15.0-1044 on Ubuntu 22.04. While the latest available drivers work seamlessly on the generic and low latency kernels for Ubuntu 22.04, I encounter an error on the real-time kernel: "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

Is there a known workaround, unofficial patch, or any suggestion to address this issue on the real-time kernel?

I've encountered an issue under the real-time kernel: the NVIDIA driver doesn't seem to be loading. I verified this by running the command: `lsmod | grep nvidia`. Unfortunately, there was no output, indicating that the driver isn't active

I received an error message indicating that the real-time kernel, due to its PREEMPT nature, isn't compatible with the NVIDIA driver. Currently addressing this would necessitate a driver patch tailored for the latest real-time kernel.

Comment: I've encountered an issue under the real-time kernel: the NVIDIA driver doesn't seem to be loading. I verified this by running the command: lsmod | grep nvidia   Unfortunately, there was no output, indicating the driver isn't active.

Comment: I received an error message indicating that the real-time kernel, due to its PREEMPT nature, isn't compatible with the NVIDIA driver. Currently, addressing this would necessitate a driver patch tailored for the latest real-time kernel.